# Failing to produce unicode strings dynamically

Tags: java, unicode

In UI of my application i am using Unicode strings ranging from "\u0900" to "\u0959" which are unicode equivalent of some Devanagari characters.
I am trying to generate these Unicode strings dynamically to set over the Buttons of  the UI.
Code:

```
   for(int i=900;  i<=959 ; i++){
        String buttontext = "\\"+"u"+Integer.toString(i);
        this.add(new CreateButton(buttontext)); //CreateButton extends JButton.
    }
```

It fails horribly, the strings are displayed like , \u900 to \u959 instead of Devanagari characters themsleves.
How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a unicode escape sequence like that (`"\u...."` is only recognized by the compiler). Instead, loop through the character values and create the String with [`String#valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(char)):

```
for (char i = 0x900; i <= 0x959; i++) {
    String buttontext = String.valueOf(i);
    // ...
}
```

Note that I'm prefixing the numbers with `0x`, which means that the numbers are *hexadecimal*. I do this because unicode escape sequences are composed of [4 hexadecimal digits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.3):

```
UnicodeEscape:
    \ UnicodeMarker HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit
```

Comment: Thank you! Well how did you studied java, which books you used. I have  a good grasp over logic but fail with the knowledge. Can u name some books which you used to understand java?

Comment: @Deepeshkumar I'd recommend _Effective Java_.